# Explanation of division/reduction in a binary Galois Field using bit-shifts

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields, binary

I've seen a lot of algorithms reducing the result of a multiplication in a Binary Field by using only bit-shifts and XOR. The number of positions to shift seems to be derived from the polynomial, but I wasn't able to find any proper explanation.

Example 1: Algorithm 2.41 in http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387952734-c1.pdf

Example 2: Algorithm 4 in
http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/carry-less-multiplication-instruction-in-gcm-mode-paper.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through a few examples, I finally understood it.
The explanation under 2.3.5 in Example 1 actually explains the basics very well.
The main idea is that is that you can reduce every coefficient on it's own. Instead of doing division you simply use the fact that the reduction of every power over your maximal degree $m$ can be computed by $z^a \equiv z^{a-m} * r(z)$; where $r(z)$ is your modulus without the highest power. Since this can lead to degrees higher than $m$, words besides the ones in the result can be effected. So you have to start with the highest word and continue from there.

Regarding the bit-shifts:

- Right shifts are used for the carry over from the previous word. If we assume $w$ is the word size than a right shift by $(w-b)$ returns the bits that are shifted out by left shifting by b.
- Left-shifts are used for the multiplication with $r(x)$. For every component of $r(x)$ simply shift all words that are reduced to the left by the degree of the corresponding component.